# base_name argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a .queryset attribute

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to replace the **standard queryset**:

```
queryset: MyModel.objects.all()
```

on my:

```
def get_queryset(self, username=None):
    if username is not None:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(username=username)
        queryset = MyModel.filter(author=user)
        return queryset
    else:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

when I remove the "queryset", and leave only "get_queryset", an error appears:

> AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

All together looks so:

```
class MyModelView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

permissions_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
serializer_class = MyModelleSerializer

def get_queryset(self, username=None):
    if username is not None:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(username=username)
        queryset = MyModel.filter(author=user)
        return queryset
    else:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        return queryset
    
lookup_field = 'username'
lookup_value_regex = '[a-zA-Z0-9$&(._)\-]+'
```

So how to override method correctly?

Comment: You'll also get this error if, like me, you decided to manually type out the urls.py code from the example on github; I accidentally wrote UserViewSet as a string ('UserViewSet') instead of referring to the object defined in the same file, on the line described by Rahmonov below.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

In the latest DRF, you need to explicitly set `base_name` in your viewset url if you don't have `queryset` defined.

So, something like this should do good:

```
router.register(r'my-model/', MyModelView, basename='MyModel')
```

See this: [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

Answer (score 12):

You must add an argument called `basename` for the register method in the url.py file, Like the following code in url.py :

```
"In url.py"
    
    
...
    
from rest_framework import routers
       
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'my-model/' , MyModelView , basename='MyModel')  
urlpattern=[...]
```

Comment: "basename" not "base_name"

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `basename` attribute in your url conf. [Docs here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage)

Answer (score 0):

in my case i'm using rest framework Default router and changing view name to exact match with model name solved the problem.

View:

```
class DailyQuote(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = DailyQuote.objects.all()
   serializer_class = DailyQuoteSerializer
```

Model:

```
class DailyQuote(models.Model):
   quote = models.TextField()
   text = models.TextField()
```

so just change MyModelView to Model.